How to kill android application from c++
I am developing a library to detect rooted environment & I am able to achieve that goal but since the tools like frida, lsposed etc exists, An attacker can be easily able to hook libc's function that can be used for killing the application process in malicious environment.
Example: (This type of hooking is very straightforward)
pid_t pid = getpid();
kill(pid, SIGKILL);

What is the best way to shutdown the app from c++ (JNI) side?
PS: I know it is impossible to prevent it but how to make it very difficult/tedious?

Are you trying to kill your own application or other applications?

@AlanBirtles My own application

why not just exit the application normally rather than killing it?

what do you mean? can you give an example?.  I want to protect my application from my user itself, I do not want them to run it on rooted device.

Most anti-hooking systems do not use system commands to force kill their own process, instead they execute assembler commands that cause an error that crashes their own process. This is way more difficult to detect and prevent.

@Robert Thank you for answering. can you give an example by giving it as an answer to this question?

Sorry but I have never implement such a self-kill, it was only when I was reversing apps but I do not remember the exact assembler commands.

@Robert That's okay. Thank you for the reply.

An application works on its process memory only. It can't get root permission but built-in application. You cannot kill your application itself except an ANR or Fatal report.
